# XCode 4 Unit Test: Test a Game on Runtime

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, ios5, xcode4, runtime

Is it possible to do a unit-test during runtime? And how to do it? I've already done research and all I can do is doing logical tests.

There are events where UIs will popup, do this and that. I want to test features that needs to do that, poping UI and such. So I want it to be simulated and be tested if it will pass.

Any solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Calabash](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios) is also an option, 
Also, you can use default OCUnit Application Tests